# How to implement Insertion Sort with an array of structures in C?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, struct

I'm trying to sort an array of structures but I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

This is my structure:

```
typedef struct{
    char name[15];
    char score[15];
}scores;
```

This is my file:

```
Eric 2500
John 4000
Chris 2000
Karen 1000
Lizzie 3000
```

I read the file so now my structure has the name and the score value but when I try to sort it with this Insertion Sort algorithm that my classmate gave me:

```
void InsertionSort(scores records[RP])
{
    int pos, i;
    scores structInsert;

    for(i=1; i<=RP; i++)
    {
        strcpy(structInsert.name, records[i].name);
        strcpy(structInsert.score, records[i].score);

        pos=i;

        while(pos>0 && records[pos-1].score > structInsertar.score)
        {
            strcpy(structInsert.name, records[i].name);
            strcpy(structInsert.score, records[i].score);
            pos--;
        }

        if(pos!=i)
        {
            strcpy(records[pos].name, structInsert.name);
            strcpy(records[pos].score, structInsert.score);
        }
    }
}
```

and the output after the "sort" is this:

```
?2-s //Trash, Eric is gone
John 4000
Chris 2000
Karen 1000
Lizzie 3000
```

Nothing is sorted, please help! BTW, score is a char because it's for `outtextxy()` for a game.

Comment: The range `i<=RP` seems wrong because I guess `records` have only `RP` elements according to the code `scores records[RP]` (although this is actually equivalent to `scores *records` and the information about number of elements will be gone). Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What is the meaning of the comparison `records[pos-1].score > structInsertar.score`? Since the `score` field is a character array, the above comparison compares the addresses of the array and not the actual values stored (which is what I assume was the intention). Also, the copying in the second loop does not make sense since `i` is not changed in the loop.

Comment: You also have a problem with how you are (not) moving elements within your array.  You perform copies only between the array and your temporary space, but in the inner loop you need to copy an element from one position in the array to another.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are causing *undefined behavior* by reading out-of-range of the array.

Try changing `i<=RP` to `i<RP` in order to avoid [off-by-one error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error).